# Replace Text with Image - JavaScript (getElementsByClass)

Tags: javascript, replace, getelementsbyclassname

I have a span:

```
<span class="attr attr-value">Brand Name</span>
```

And I want to replace that text with an image, based on the text

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var oldHTML = document.getElementsByClass('attr-value').innerHTML;
 var filename = oldHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/([^0-9a-z-])/g,'');
 var newHTML = "<img src='http://www.example.com/" + filename + ".jpg'>";
 document.getElementsByClass('attr-value').innerHTML = newHTML;
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This line is an issue:

```
var oldHTML = document.getElementsByClass('attr-value').innerHTML;
```

`document.getElementsByClass` should be `document.getElementsByClassName`, and it returns a `NodeList`, which doesn't have an `innerHTML` property. You'd want to loop through the `NodeList` to look at the `innerHTML` of each element.

Something like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/anevi4)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var list, index, element, filename;
    list = document.getElementsByClassName('attr-value');
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        element = list[index];
        filename = element.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/([^0-9a-z-])/g,'');
        element.innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.example.com/" + filename + ".jpg'>";
    }
})();
</script>
```

Changes:

1. Put the whole thing in an anonymous function and immediately execute that function, to avoid creating global symbols.
2. Use the correct `getElementsByClassName`
3. Loop through them
4. Operate on the `innerHTML` of each element.

Notes:

- IE doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`, so you'll want to be sure you're loading a script that provides it on IE. That's not provided in the live example above, use Firefox, Chrome, or Opera. (Just search for "getElementsByClassName for IE" and you'll find several implementations to choose from.)
- The above `script` tag will need to be placed after all of the elements you want to process in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

It should be, (e.g)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('attr-value')[0];
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. You're treating `getElementsByClassName` (the function, not its result) like an array.

Comment: Now that you've fixed the first error: This new version is only doing the first one. He clearly wants to do all of them.

Answer (score 1):

- `class="attr attr-value"`  and you're calling 
  `document.getElementsByClass('attr-value').innerHTML`
- `document.getElementsByClassName()`;

Comment: *"class="attr attr-value" and you're calling document.getElementsByClass('attr-value').innerHTML"* So? The `class` attribute sets *two* classes, and he's querying by one of them. Assuming it's okay that the returned elements may not have the other class, that's not a problem.